# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS внутри админки Prestashop

Tags: php, redirect, prestashop

Prestashop версии 1.6.1.18
В разделе каталог->товары админки CMS загружается первая страница с списком товаров, далее при нажатии любой ссылки пагинации через секунд 5 загрузки выходит ошибка браузера - "Сайт выполнил переадресацию слишком много раз ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"

URL - мойСайт/админка/index.php?controller=AdminProducts&token=776564214b6f27c83fa2a98ae186961d&submitFilterproduct=2#product

На всех страницах клиентской стороны сайта такого нет, в других местах админки тоже. Только в разделе товаров

Удаление кэша, обновление файла htaccess и переустановка SSL не помогли

Подскажите что это может быть, или в каком месте искать причины ошибки

Comment: Магазин переносили локально на хостинг или необорот? После чего появилась даная ошибка?

Comment: Нет не переносили, недавно делали обновление с версии 1.6.1.12